# Laravel ignoring both env and config files

Tags: php, laravel, apache, email

Today I started a new laravel Project but I can not set anything in the env and config files. It is a simple project to send emails but it ignores the env and config reading the php.ini instead.

First I was using artisan serve, cleaning cache and stuff. After hours trying I start to use apache24. But even I having setting the values on both files it remains ignoiring that and using values from php.ini.

What makes me think it might not be a laravel issue, but PHP.

Has anyone else gone through this?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot set config via code something like this `Config:set('key','value')` ?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of `php.ini` and `.env` are entirely different and serve different purposes. `php.ini` is designed to configure PHP *itself* where `.env` loads environment variables that are used by Laravel for its configuration.

If you are trying to set PHP configuration in `.env` then of course it is not going to do anything.